# Is mean squared error equivalent to mean squared absolute error

Tags: absolute-value, square-numbers, mean-square-error

It is a simple question. But, I want to make sure I am not missing any crucial assumptions. Is this

$A = (\hat{Y} - Y)^2$

same as

$B = (|\hat{Y} - Y|)^2$

Main concern: If $A$ returns negative inside the parentheses, we are squaring it, so it becomes positive. And, $B$ takes the absolute value and then squares it. At end, $A$ and $B$ return the same answer, using different mechanisms to "enforce" positivity. If $\hat{Y}$ and $Y$ are real numbers, does that makes $A$ and $B$ same?

Comment: For real numbers $x^2=|x|^2$. For complex values $i^2=-1\neq 1=|i|^2$.

Comment: @spiralstotheleft here we are concerned about $(x)^2$, not $x^2$, right?

Comment: What is the difference between $(x)^2$ and $x^2?$

Comment: @saulspatz I mean $-x^2$ is negative of $x^2$ and $(-x)^2$ is the square of negative $x$.

Comment: But there are no negative signs in your previous comment.  I can't understand what you mean.  $(x)^2=x^2,$ always, unconditionally.

Comment: @saulspatz that is my mistake. My main question is, if $A$ returns negative inside the parentheses, we are squaring it, so it becomes positive. And, $B$ takes the absolute value and then squares it. At end, $A$ and $B$ return the same answer, using different mechanisms to "enforce" positivity. If $\hat{Y}$ and $Y$ are real numbers, does that makes A and B same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. You can use a syllogism:

- If $\hat{Y}$ and $Y$ are real numbers, then $\hat{Y} -  Y$ is a real number
- If $x$ is a real number, then $x^2=\left(|x|\right)^2$
- So, if $\hat{Y}$ and $Y$ are real numbers, then $\left(\hat{Y} -  Y\right)^2 =\left(\left|\hat{Y} -  Y\right|\right)^2$